# Randomized algorithm do determine if two matrix differs in one entry?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, probability

Alice and Bob have two n*n binary matrix, A and B, respectively.

They want to know if A=B except only one entry.

I need to design a randomized algorithm with one-way mistake in which Alice sends to Bob only one message in size of O(n(log(n)^2)) bytes.

- Bob returns only "Yes" or "No".
- If A=B except only one entry Bob will return "Yes" in probability of 1.
- Otherwise, Bob will return "No" in probability of at least 1/2.

my solution for now:
What Alice do:
create polynomial P(x) for each row and for each column in A, find primary number q, 4n^2<=a<=5n^2, find number t, 1<=t<=q and calculate P(t) for each polynomial we created.calculate P(t)modq for each polynomial. send to Bob the result off each p(t)modq calculation,q and t.
What Bob do:
create polynomial P(x) for each row and for each column in A.
calculate P(t) for each polynomial we created.calculate P(t)modq for each polynomial.
Now let's say we have Pi(x) for row i and Pj(x) for column j. if the result of Pi(t)modq and Pj(t)modq is different from what Alice sent, then we know that we have different bits in the [i,j] entry. if we have only one difference then we return "Yes", otherwise, we return "No".

I don;t know if that algorithm is good because in the question they asked for an algorithm which sends a message in size of O(n(log(n)^2)) bytes and here we sends a message in size of O(n(log(n))) bytes

please help me :)

Comment: You haven't asked any question here.

Comment: Is this homework? You might want to say what you have actually tried and how we may help you. You can't ask for a complete solution to a problem.

Comment: Specifically what is meant by "one-way mistake"?

Comment: I removed "please help me" from your question because we're hear to help you - requesting that we do doesn't add anything to the question (and we're not particularly fond of anything that distracts from the actual question in a post here on [so]).

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo, i'm not asking for a complete solution, i'm asking for some thoughts that may guide me to the answer.

Comment: @shuttle87, it means that if the matrix differs in one entry, then bob will always return "yes", otherwise, we will get "no" in high probability

Comment: @kitsuneFox what is the expected outcome for the case where A=B exactly?

Comment: @shuttle87, Bow will return "No"

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo, i edited the question and wrote what i did for now, please help me now

Comment: @kitsuneFox: How about saying something if one of the two answers has helped you or why they didn´t?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood:
`n*n` matrices A and B, each entry `0` or `1`; Alice has A, Bob has B
Only one message passed, max. `O(n*log^2(n))` byte
If exactly one entry differs, return 1 (Yes).
Else, return 0 (No) in at least 50% of cases (including "no entry differs").

Easy solution:
Reduce all `n*n` matrix entries to one bit by XOR-ing all values,
(for both A and B), the Abit is the message (length constant 1 bit).
Bob compares the Abit to his Bbit. If different "Yes", else "No".

If exactly one bit in the matrix is flipped, they ill be different for sure.
If the matrices are identical, it´s "No".
For all other natural numbers, you´ll get "No" for even count, else "Yes"
=> exactly one "No" more than Yes´es, over the whole natural numbers,
because the missing Yes is the special case.
=> More than 50% "No" for all casses but the special one.

But maybe I didn´t understand the problem, because somehow it´s too easy...

Comment: If the matrices are different in more than one column they may get the same XOR value.

Comment: I know, but <50% as described

Comment: Bob has to be 100% on "Yes". If the bits are different it doesn't necessarily mean that they are different in only one entry.

Comment: Please read the question (and the clarifying comments) again. If there is exactly 1 difference, it has to be 100% "Yes". Anything else: At least 50% "No".

Comment: that's not really the exact meaning of randomized algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. That's what I would do. I think a form of hashing is apt for this scenario. You need to create hashes for each row and column and pass it to Bob. Bob would then compare his own matrix by using the same hashing scheme and check to see which hash is different if any.

I think here the hashing function is the most important part of the question. You need to find a function that would be able to work with 2^n different numbers and hash them into a max of (nlog(n)^2)/2 byte number whilst satisfying the proper probability considerations of the problem(50%). If the hash function is able to do that then you are passing 2n hashes and would not pass the limit.

I don't think you need to worry about your message sizes being less than the limit asked though.

Comment: i don't need hashing since it's just a pseudo code, but if you say that it looks good then i'm happy, but that message size is still makes me worried